# Flutter and Firebase: Apple Sign-In not working, no sign-in window opens up

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I am facing difficulties implementing Apple Sign-In in my Flutter project using Firebase. The button associated with the sign-in function doesn't trigger any action, and the sign-in window does not open up. I have tried various methods and functions, so I suspect that the issue lies in the implementation rather than the code itself. It is worth noting that I added Sign-In with Apple using Xcode, but I do not run the project through Xcode. Instead, I use Codemagic to send the code to TestFlight and test the app from there.

i have done the following:

- add service id (Website URLs https://APP_ID.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler too)
- add key
- add the capability in the developer console and through xcode (though i dont run the app through xcode as i stated before)
- add an email to Email Addresses in services

info.plist:

```xml
    <!-- Sign in Providers -->
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- Google Sign-In -->
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>com.googleusercontent......</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <!-- Apple Sign-In -->
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>my.app.id</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <!-- Facebook Sign-In -->
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>fb.......</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>FacebookAppID</key>
        <string>......</string>
        <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
        <string>.................</string>
        <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
        <string>.....</string>
        <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbapi</string>
            <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
            <string>fbauth2</string>
            <string>fbshareextension</string>
        </array>

        <!-- Added keys   -->
```

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple.dart';

import 'auth_util.dart';

// / Generates a cryptographically secure random nonce, to be included in a
// / credential request.
String generateNonce([int length = 32]) {
  final charset =
      '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._';
  final random = Random.secure();
  return List.generate(length, (_) => charset[random.nextInt(charset.length)])
      .join();
}

/// Returns the sha256 hash of [input] in hex notation.
String sha256ofString(String input) {
  final bytes = utf8.encode(input);
  final digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
  return digest.toString();
}

Future<UserCredential> appleSignIn() async {
  if (kIsWeb) {
    final provider = OAuthProvider("apple.com")
      ..addScope('email')
      ..addScope('name');

    // Sign in the user with Firebase.
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }
  // To prevent replay attacks with the credential returned from Apple, we
  // include a nonce in the credential request. When signing in in with
  // Firebase, the nonce in the id token returned by Apple, is expected to
  // match the sha256 hash of `rawNonce`.
  final rawNonce = generateNonce();
  final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);

  // Request credential for the currently signed in Apple account.
  final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
    scopes: [
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
    ],
    nonce: nonce,
  );

  // Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.
  final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
    idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
    rawNonce: rawNonce,
  );

  // Sign in the user with Firebase. If the nonce we generated earlier does
  // not match the nonce in `appleCredential.identityToken`, sign in will fail.
  return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
}

Future<User?> signInWithApple(BuildContext context) =>
    signInOrCreateAccount(context, appleSignIn, 'APPLE');
```

Im working on this for over a week and haven't found a solution yet